# Output redirect with fork&execvp

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, posix

I have a program that prints output to stdout:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 1:
    valualuee = 1
else:
    value = sys.argv[1]

counter = 0
while counter < 100:
    print value
    time.sleep(0.1)
    counter = counter+1
```

Then I want at program that executes 2 instances of it with different arguments.
In that program I want to specify in which file that program's stdout is redirected.

After both programs have finished, I want to print something again in the main console, which fails.

I also want to be able to see one program's output on the console in addition to its output in the file.

This is my try:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess
import sys
import os
import time

###########################################
def background(program, argument, logfile):
    #redirect stdout
    sys.stdout = open(logfile, "w")
    os.dup2(sys.stdout.fileno(), 1)

    try:
        pid=os.fork()
    except OSError, e:
        sys.exit(1)

    if pid==0:  #in the forked process
        ex = "./" + program
        os.execvp(ex, [ex, argument])

    return pid
###########################################


pid1 = background("program1.py", "1", "log1")
pid2 = background("program1.py", "2", "log2")

os.waitpid(pid1, 0)
os.waitpid(pid2, 0)

#print in console again
print "done"
```

Comment: What fails? How does it fail? What is your question?

Comment: Having said that... you are overwriting `sys.stdout` in `background` so that future `print` statements (even in the parent) are going into the log file. You probably want to open your new standard output in the child after the fork. Also, no need to use `sys.stdout`. Open the log file and use `dup2` to force the resulting file descriptor to 1 before `exec`ing. Then `sys.stdout` inside the child`program1.py` process will have the right value but will be unchanged in the parent.

Comment: With moving open and dup2 calls in the forked process, everything goes where it should now. How can I now have one child's output in the console too (the parent's stdout)?